# How to send volley request one after another

Tags: android, android-volley

I have few SQL queries that I need to send using Volley. 
When I send only one request, everything works fine. But now I need to send a couple of requests, one after another without waiting for answers..

When responses will arrive, I need to know which response belongs to which request...

Please advice how to deal with that...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 void sendParam(String url, final Context context)
{



    StringRequest strRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response)
                {


                    sendParam1(url1,context);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {

                }
            })
    {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String,String> param = new HashMap<String,String>();


            return  param;
        }
    };


    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(strRequest);


}
```

and then call another method

```
 void sendParam1(String url1,final Context context)
{
    StringRequest request=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url1, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }){

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String,String> param = new HashMap<String,String>();


            return  param;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how many requests I have to send... I have a list with data and for each row I have to send a query..

Comment: @IgorKushnir then make method call in a for loop with list size condition